# Alternative for storing id in hidden input

Tags: php

Normally, when editing something, say when admin is approving a comment to a product, the `id` of the comment is stored in `<input type="hidden">` to be included during form submission. But with this, just a change to the `id` may affect other pending comment, or those that are already approved.

So instead I used `password_hash` to hash the `comment id`, and stores it with the original `comment id` in a session array. Then after submitting the form, I check the submitted hashed `comment id` to the session array, looking for a match, then getting the original `comment id`.

Here's how I generate the hashed `comment id`:

```
foreach ($pendingComments as $comment) {
    $commentId = $comment['Id'];
    $hashed = password_hash($commentId, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $_SESSION['COMMENT_IDS'][] = ['hash'=>$hashed, 'id'=>$commentId];
    $customerName = $comment['GivenName'] . ' ' . $comment['Surname'];
    $message = $comment['Message'];
    $timestamp = $comment['Timestamp'];
    echo '
        <tr>
            <td>' . $customerName . '</td>
            <td>' . $message . '</td>
            <td>' . $timestamp . '</td>
            <td>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" value="'.$hashed.'" name="commentId">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" name="changeCommentStatus" value="1">Approve</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" name="changeCommentStatus" value="2">Reject</button>
                </form>
             </td>
         </tr>
    ';
}
```

Here's how I check for a match after submission:

```
if (isset($_POST['changeCommentStatus'])) {
    $hashedId = $_POST['commentId'];
    $status = $_POST['changeCommentStatus'];
    $commentId = '';
    foreach ($_SESSION['COMMENT_IDS'] as $data) {
        $hash = $data['hash'];
        $id = $data['id'];
        if ($hashedId === $hash) {
            $commentId = $id;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (empty($commentId)) {
        // this means that the $hashedId didn't matched anything, which also means that it has been altered
        // redirect back to the page and says that the id is invalid
    }
    echo $commentId;die;
}
$_SESSION['COMMENT_IDS'] = [];
```

As of now, it is working. But I'm not sure if there are any critical disadvantage /drawbacks or something, or if this is not recommended at all.

**Note:**

- Some may say that an admin will not intentionally alter the source or something, but I'm planning to use this every time I need to use `<input type="hidden" >`
- This may be more useful if while a user edits his comment, and somehow changed the `comment id` to another `comment id` that also belongs to the same user, instead the other comment has been edited
- I can somehow prevent the action if the replaced `comment id` belonged to another user, preventing the current user from indirectly editing other users' comments
- And of course, this is also to be used for other content that uses `<input type="hidden">`, especially when editing, not just for comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would question the premise.

> But with this, just a change to the id may affect other pending comment, or those that are already approved.

I don't see a problem here.

Given the admin is allowed to approve any comment, and nobody else is authorized to access this page completely, I don't see how it's even a problem.

To put it bluntly, nobody in the world is using such a clumsy approach as it's either useless or has a completely different solution (to ensure that a user cannot access other users' records there should be an ACL system in the database, not some HTML/Session ratatouille).

Comment: Although I agree about admin part, I was planning on using it for users also. Regardless, I'll research about the ACL system for other solution.